# How to find a string in an NSArray?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsarray

This feels like such a stupid question, but how can I find a string in an `NSArray`?

I tried using

```
[array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:myString]
```

but that requires the sting to have the same address.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You want [the `indexOfObject:` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:), which looks for the object by sending each object in the array an `isEqual:` message.

Answer (score 13):

Peter's answer is correct.

One additional note;  if you have tons and tons of strings in the array, `-indexOfObject:` is going to do a linear search.   This may prove to be a performance bottleneck for which you should consider using a different container;  an NSSet or NSDictionary, possibly (depending on what the strings mean).

Another gotcha is if the strings are all relatively similar and/or relatively long.

**Of course, don't bother optimizing anything until you have used the analysis tools to prove that you have a performance issue.**

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSOrderSet as the container, the over view in NSOrderedSet Class Reference is below:

> NSOrderedSet and its subclass, NSMutableOrderedSet, declare the programmatic interfaces to an ordered collection of objects.
>
> NSOrderedSet declares the programmatic interface for static sets of distinct objects. You >establish a static set’s entries when it’s created, and thereafter the entries can’t be >modified. NSMutableOrderedSet, on the other hand, declares a programmatic interface for >dynamic sets of distinct objects. A dynamic—or mutable—set allows the addition and deletion >of entries at any time, automatically allocating memory as needed.
>
> You can use ordered sets as an alternative to arrays when the order of elements is important >and performance in testing whether an object is contained in the set is a consideration— >testing for membership of an array is slower than testing for membership of a set.

Visit http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

**containsObject:**

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object is present in the array.

- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
  Parameters
  anObject
  An object.

**Return Value**
YES if anObject is present in the array, otherwise NO.

**Discussion**

This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by sending an isEqual: message to each of the array’s objects (and passing anObject as the parameter to each isEqual: message).

**Declared In**

NSArray.h